# Получение имен загружаемых файлов

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить все имена загружаемых файлов, которые видны при наведении:

[image: пример]

С помощью функции `getName(str)` получаю только имя первого файла:

```js
function getName (str) {
    if (str.lastIndexOf('\\')) {
        var i = str.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
    }
    else {
        var i = str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
    }      
    var filename = str.slice(i);   
    var uploaded = document.getElementById("fileformlabel");
    uploaded.innerHTML = filename;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" multiple="" accept="image/*,application/msword" onchange="getName(this.value);" />
<div id="fileformlabel"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не очень ясно мне, что именно вы хотите делать в функции `getName`. Вот пример функции, которая возвращает массив имен загружаемых файлов:

```js
var upload = document.getElementById("upload");

function getFileNames() {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(upload.files, function(file) {
    return file.name;
  });
}

upload.onchange = function() {
  alert(getFileNames());
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" multiple>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как вывести эти значения не в `alert` , в строку, как на скриншоте?

Comment: А людей не пугает конструкция `Array.prototype.map.call`? :)

Comment: @Regent `<input type="file" id="upload" multiple>
            <div id="fileformlabel"></div>
  <script>
var upload = document.getElementById("upload");
var uploaded = document.getElementById("fileformlabel");

function getFileNames() {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(upload.files, function(file) {
    return file.name;
  });
}

upload.innerHTML = function() {
  getFileNames());
}

uploaded.innerHTML = getFileNames();
</script>` Не получается, что не так делаю?

Comment: @Николай а что насчет синтаксической ошибки (которая видна в консоли) в строке `getFileNames());` (`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"`)?

Comment: @Николай а если убрать другие ошибки, то получится [что-то вроде этого](http://jsfiddle.net/39150rp9/1/).

Comment: @Regent Мне удивительно, что Вы так часто помогаете людей в комментариях, но от этого репутацию не получаете. Молодец)

Comment: @Regent Сейчас имена выводятся в массиве в одну строку, можно ли как то в несколько строк их разместить? Чтобы каждое имя в своей строке?

Comment: @PeterOlson да репутация-то ладно (главное чтобы хватало на правки  без утверждения и на закрытие вопросов). Плохо что иногда авторов в комментариях "уносит" достаточно далеко от изначального вопроса.

Comment: @Николай Можно [как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/39150rp9/2/).

Comment: @Regent Не поскажите еще как можно при нажатии на Delete удалять один из элементов?[здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/39150rp9/5/) Я тут что-то неправильно делаю:  `uploaded.innerHTML.find('Delete').click(function(){
                        $(this).parent().remove();
                        thisInput.remove();
                    });`

Comment: @Николай нет, не подскажу: это уже не имеет отношения к данному вопросу. Задайте новый вопрос с описанием данной проблемы. Думаю, ответ был бы дан за считанные минуты.